# Can't achieve JSON structure using Lodash

Tags: javascript, json, nested, chaining, lodash

I'm still having a hard time trying to figure out which methods to use. I'm playing with the earlier lodash solution that was given to me so I can learn how Lodash is working. What's currently happening is that the output is becoming an object and the deviceModels are turning into keys. I was expecting this kind of output

`[
    {
        "deviceModel": "Canon450MX",
        "overallTotal": 75,
        "deviceCount": 3,
        "dates": [
            {
                "date": "2014-09-01T05:00:00Z",
                "deviceModel": "Canon450MX", // This can be removed
                "totalInchesPrinted": 30
            },
            {
                "date": "2014-09-01T06:00:00Z",
                "deviceModel": "Canon450MX", // This can be removed
                "totalInchesPrinted": 180
            },
            {
                "date": "2014-09-01T06:00:00Z",
                "deviceModel": "Canon450MX", // This can be removed
                "totalInchesPrinted": 45
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "deviceModel": "Canon9000ST",
        "overallTotal": 645,
        "deviceCount": 3,
        "dates": [
            {
                "date": "2014-09-01T06:00:00Z",
                "deviceModel": "Canon9000ST", // This can be removed
                "totalInchesPrinted": 600
            },
            {
                "date": "2014-09-01T06:00:00Z",
                "deviceModel": "Canon9000ST", // This can be removed
                "totalInchesPrinted": 45
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "deviceModel": "HPDeskjet",
        "overallTotal": 76,
        "deviceCount": 3,
        "dates": [
            {
                "date": "2014-09-01T05:00:00Z",
                "deviceModel": "HPDeskjet", // This can be removed
                "totalInchesPrinted": 40
            },
            {
                "date": "2014-09-01T06:00:00Z",
                "deviceModel": "HPDeskjet", // This can be removed
                "totalInchesPrinted": 6
            },
            {
                "date": "2014-09-01T07:00:00Z",
                "deviceModel": "HPDeskjet", // This can be removed
                "totalInchesPrinted": 30
            }
        ]
    }
]`

But the output is being generated like this
`{
    "Canon450MX": [
        {
            "date": "2014-09-01T05:00:00Z",
            "deviceModel": "Canon450MX",
            "totalInchesPrinted": 30
        },
        {
            "date": "2014-09-01T06:00:00Z",
            "deviceModel": "Canon450MX",
            "totalInchesPrinted": 180
        },
        {
            "date": "2014-09-01T07:00:00Z",
            "deviceModel": "Canon450MX",
            "totalInchesPrinted": 45
        }
    ],
    "Canon9000ST": [
        {
            "date": "2014-09-01T06:00:00Z",
            "deviceModel": "Canon9000ST",
            "totalInchesPrinted": 600
        },
        {
            "date": "2014-09-01T07:00:00Z",
            "deviceModel": "Canon9000ST",
            "totalInchesPrinted": 45
        }
    ],
    "HPDeskjet": [
        {
            "date": "2014-09-01T05:00:00Z",
            "deviceModel": "HPDeskjet",
            "totalInchesPrinted": 40
        },
        {
            "date": "2014-09-01T06:00:00Z",
            "deviceModel": "HPDeskjet",
            "totalInchesPrinted": 6
        },
        {
            "date": "2014-09-01T07:00:00Z",
            "deviceModel": "HPDeskjet",
            "totalInchesPrinted": 30
        }
    ]
}`

Here is my JS Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ohgenLr5/2/

Also, I would like to know how I can add overallTotal and deviceCount(shown above) based on unique serial number for that day.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: The groupBy call seems to be the thing that is turning the list into an object with deviceModel keys.

Comment: Ok. Should I use .map again like this?
.map(transformDeviceModels).flatten().sortBy('deviceModel').map(someOtherFunction)
.value();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do an additional `map` after `groupBy` to get the structure you want, using `reduce` to get the sum of total inches printed...

```
var data = _.chain(list[0].dates)
    .map(transformDeviceModels)
    .flatten()
    .sortBy('deviceModel')
    .groupBy('deviceModel')
    .map(function(printers, model) {
        return {
            deviceModel: model,
            overallTotal: _.reduce(printers, function(sum, printer) {
                return sum + printer.totalInchesPrinted;
            }, 0),
            deviceCount: printers.length,
            dates: printers
        };
    })
    .value();
```

[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/yihusubuhiju/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: I'm going to take a look Anthony. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: WOW! That is awesome Anthony!!! Thank you so much!!! :) This will help me learn Lodash faster!!! :)

Comment: I still cannot up the point since my reputation is only 3. I just recently joined stackoverflow.

Comment: No worries. Glad to help. If you don't want the model in the dates you can use `omit`... `dates: _.map(printers, function(p) { return _.omit(p, 'deviceModel'); })`